# send a list of string elements in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, unicode

I am new to Django. This is my Tag model

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    post=models.ManyToManyField('Post')
```

I send a list of all tags name to a template. I want to use it in a javascript code. The problem is that, the list looks like this in javascript

```
 [u&#39;c++&#39;, u&#39;c#&#39;, u&#39;php&#39;, u&#39;python&#39;,
 u&#39;django&#39;]
```

It should be as this

> ['c++', 'c#', 'php', 'python', 'django']

I think it's some thing about unicode, but I do not know how to handel it. any help please?

excuse my bad english

Comment: What does your template and view look like?

Comment: I encoded the list to JSON in the view then decoded it in the javascript code $.parseJSON('{{tags | safe}}') . Thank you for mentioning the safe filter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell me whether the mistake is when you render the first time the view, or is an ajax call?, I think you are doing ajax call, then can you debug the django process, and write here what are the datas that you recover of your database, please?.

In addition, can you put the json serializer that you are using please?

If you try the next code, you can see the problem is not unicode:

```
         import json
         json.dumps([unicode(i) for i in range(10)])

result: '["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]'
```

try send the above data, and tell us the result please. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, I encoded the list to JSON in the view then decoded it in the javascript code
 $.parseJSON('{{tags | safe}}')

Comment: The output of `dumps()` is not safe to include in a `<script>` block and should not be marked `|safe`. An attacker could put the string `</script><script>attack()` in a tag and get cross-site-scripting. You can `|escapejs` the JSON string to make it suitable for inclusion in a JavaScript string, then use `JSON.parse()` from the JS side to decode the structure again. More commonly, you can put the JSON-encoded data in a `data-` attribute (with the standard HTML escaping Django does automatically) and read it out of the DOM from JS using eg jQuery's `$(...).data()` which will handle JSON for you

Answer (score 0):

Use "|safe"

something like this in your template.

```
{{ variable_name | safe }}
```

Comment: thanks , but the list is not as I want it to be
after adding safe filter , the list = [u'c++', u'c#', u'php', u'python', u'django']